# Google Analytics data still being populated months later

Tags: google-analytics

I pull a report for new users to my site every month. Ive gone and looked at those numbers again, and the numbers for all the previous months (up to 7 months ago) have increased by around 30 new users.

Why would this be? Im using a 360 account so the refresh rate should be around 8 hours max - but it seems like old data is still being pulled into GA months later.

Any advice as to why this would be tru would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out google documentations?

Comment: i have looked at the data freshness documentation ( https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7084038?hl=en ). I see that data refresh rate is 24 - 48 hours on a standard account. My account being 360 should be considerably faster than that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better  suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/